# Restoring snapshot in Acumatica disables some indices

Tags: indexing, acumatica, snapshot

When restoring a snapshot in a 2018 Acumatica database, some table indices become disabled.  Has anyone seen this before?  What could cause it?  How can I complete the restoration successfully?

Comment: Is it a Full Text Index?

Comment: No it is a table index

Comment: It is difficult for me to assess why it is not re-enabling indexes but I believe there are cases where it's needed to Disable and Rebuild indexes. Maybe this was a fluke. A workaround after snapshot restore could be to open the Acumatica ERP Configuration Wizard that matches the instance version, go to Perform Application Maintenance section, select your instance row in the grid, click on the arrow right of Upgrade and choose Update Only Database. When version are the same it doesn't update but rather repair the database and there's a pass in there that attempts to re-enable disabled indexes.

Comment: Problem is now resolved.  We discovered there was an improperly formed primary key in the original script that created the database table.  Best practice is to form the primary key as a constraint on the table, and name it <table_name>_PK.  This way when the indices are dropped and rebuilt during snapshot restoration, the primary key is not lost.